# javascript display none not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a nav bar show when a button(icon) is clicked and disappear when it is clicked again. The first part works where it shows but then when clicked again, nothing happens. I can't figure out why the second part is being ignored. Thank you

```
let nav = document.querySelector("nav");
let icon = document.querySelector(".mobile-icon");
console.log(nav);
icon.addEventListener("click", showMenu)

function showMenu() {
if (nav.style.display = "none"){
nav.style.display = "block";
} else {
    nav.style.display = "none";
}

}
```

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` and `===` are for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [**equality operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) `===` when comparing the `display` string value. You're currently using an assignment operator:

```
function showMenu() {
  if (nav.style.display === "none"){
    nav.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    nav.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow that was a silly mistake.  Thanks a lot. I'll mark as correct when allowed.

Comment: Great to hear. Thanks.